# React material how to theming body color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to change the default body color
using CssBaseline in react material?

I don't want using like

```
typography: {

    h2: {
      color: "red",
    },
  },
```

but globally is this possible ?

I don't find any example.

### UPDATE

It works with

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        body: {
          backgroundColor: "red",
          color: "green",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Watch out you must have CssBaseline nested to MuiThemeProvider

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <App />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, brother, you can override everything globally in material UI, Here I write some Inputs, Buttons, Labels globally.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Box, CssBaseline } from "@material-ui/core";

import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import App from "../App";

class Layout extends Component {
  /**
   * Render
   */
  render() {
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        secondary: {
          light: "green",
          main: "green",
          dark: "green",
          boxShadow: "none",
        },
        background: {
          default: "red",
        },
      },
    });

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />

        <Box component="div">
          <App />
        </Box>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the right answer thanks the same for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of how you can set background color globally, similarly you can add typography configurations in the theme

```
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";

    const theme = createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        background: {
          default: "#303030"
        }
      }
    });
    function App() {
      return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Your Componennt />
          </React.Fragment>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      );
    }
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: color: {
          default: "#303030"
        } doesn't work :)

Comment: can you try this const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        background: {
            paper: '#303030'
        }
    }
});